# Cisco ASA looping broadcast packet

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, security, loop

I have small office where running cisco ASA `ASA5506` and version `9.4(1)` and it's also configured for IPsec VPN tunnel, My LAN subnet is `10.1.1.0/24`

So i have found very interesting things in LAN where if i `ping 10.1.1.255` (broadcast address) it create nuclear reaction and my packet goes in loop and fill my LAN with traffic and my cisco ASA CPU goes `100%`

This is what strom looks in tcpdump

```
14:38:06.940137 IP 10.1.1.49 > 10.1.1.255: ICMP echo request, id 14677, seq 0, length 64
14:38:06.940387 IP 10.1.1.49 > 10.1.1.255: ICMP echo request, id 14677, seq 0, length 64
14:38:06.940389 IP 10.1.1.49 > 10.1.1.255: ICMP echo request, id 14677, seq 0, length 64
14:38:06.940390 IP 10.1.1.49 > 10.1.1.255: ICMP echo request, id 14677, seq 0, length 64
14:38:06.940550 IP 10.1.1.49 > 10.1.1.255: ICMP echo request, id 14677, seq 0, length 64
14:38:06.940685 IP 10.1.1.49 > 10.1.1.255: ICMP echo request, id 14677, seq 0, length 64
```

This is how i stop strom, clearing conn in ASA

`ASA# clear conn address 10.1.1.49`

I believe cisco ASA participating to amplify this storm. here is the basic config snippets of ASA

```
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
```

Notes: I believe one of above option has something to do with this storm.

Routes

```
S*    0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via 26.172.22.1, outside
C        10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, inside
L        10.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, inside
```

## EDIT

I found this link in google but not clean this is my issue or not https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/116170-probsol-asa-00.html

Comment: Satish, we need to see your topology.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to any of the bugfix releases in the 9.4(x) series to see if this was addressed already? 9.4(1) is pretty ancient and full of bugs.

Comment: It feel like `same-security-traffic permit intra-interface ` causing hair-pin issue and sending traffic back to host and creating strom. i will see if i can take that option out and make some adjustment around it.

Comment: @Satish Possibly, but Cisco switches, for example, and by default, do not allow directed broadcasts for this and other reasons. It seems more like a bug that a security device such as an ASA WOULD allow for it, which is why I'm wondering if this was addressed in updates since 9.4(1), since that was the base release and had hundreds of bugs in it. So, have you tried updating to the latest release in the 9.4(x) series to see if this still works?

Comment: @JesseP. I have try to look for  9.4.1 bugs but didn't find any clue or evidence, I will try to upgrade and see if it can be fix.

Comment: @Satish There are bugs that simply may not be known about, that were inadvertently fixed as part of another known bug, so it's worth a shot.  Especially since 9.4(1) is so old an unstable anyway.

Comment: Have you tried to recreate without the ASA connected to see if it is actually creating the storm?

Comment: I got window tomorrow to try something, can i safely upgrade from 9.4.1 to 9.6.x version, we have very basic configuration on ASA nothing fancy, running VPN anyconnect and basic ACL/NAT rules. (i don't have any place i can test so if anyone has any experience i would like to know)

Comment: I have tried to remove `intra-interface` option but that didn't help so finally i tried this which works `access-list DENY_BROADCAT ip any host 10.1.1.255` apply acl in inside LAN interface. This is not a permanent solution, i will upgrade software coming week and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrade to newer version 9.8.2 resolved all of the issue. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Accept your answer so this doesn't keep coming up as unanswered.